# Convert front panel screenshot to base64 string using LabVIEW 2018

Tags: labview

I need to convert the screenshot of the front panel of the application into a Base64 string to post it to a web API. The block diagram is:
[image]

I used a "base64_fast_encode" utility vi from the link

https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Programs/Fast-Base64-Encoder-Decoder-using-LabVIEW/ta-p/3503281

Please find the encoded base64 string file from the link: 
https://fil.email/WFBxwWyr

I pasted the resultant encoded base64 string in the below website:

https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter#

And I observed that it is not decoded back to image.

Please suggest if there are any other utility vis to convert to base64. If not, suggest an alternative of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code. What format are you getting the image in? What's your reference for 'correct' base64 encoding? Have you confirmed that you can successfully post an image that was encoded by some other tool outside LabVIEW?

Comment: I made the changes to the question. Please take a look. And by correct base64 encoding, I meant that when we decode the base64 string, image has to be displayed.

Comment: `Image Data` from the `FP.Get Image` invoke node is a LabVIEW image cluster, whose format is [described here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvpict/write_jpeg_file/) for example. Are you sure that's the same format that your website is expecting, rather than, say, the base64 encoded contents of a PNG or JPG file? What happens if you write the image to a JPG file (as per the link) then read the file contents and do the base64 encoding on that?

Comment: I tried it that way as well. And again It's the same result. It won't get decoded back to image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is converting the LabVIEW image data to a more generic image format that would be understood outside of the context of LabVIEW, such as by the CodeBeautify tool. All you need to do is convert Image Data using *LV Image to PNG Data.VI* to PNG before you encode it.

Using the below example, if I take the base64 encoded string output and use the CodeBeautify *base64-to-image-converter* tool, it does show the expected image.

[image: Example]